# MS Excel VBA - Get file names within subfolders of a declared folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through all subfolders within a folder, compiling all the names of the files. I'm having a bit of trouble though as I have adapted this code from a macro that only loops through one folder and compiles file names. Thank you greatly for your time!

```
Sub FindFiles()

Cells(1, 1).Select

Dim F As String
Dim G As String

F = Dir("C:\Users\z003nttv\Desktop\Folder\" & "*")
Do While Len(F) > 0

Do While Len(G) > 0
G = Dir(F & "*.*")
ActiveCell.Formula = G
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
G = Dir()
Loop
F = Dir()
Loop
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer at the following site:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2994-excel-list-all-files-in-folder-and-subfolders.html

Hope it may lend some help..very user friendly!

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this code before you posted the link and had second thoughts posting my work. So I checked out the link you posted.  I believe that the code I wanted to post is succinct & addresses the point far better. Hence here you go

> Step 1. The Reference

[image: References needed for this code]

> Step2. The Code.

```
Sub FindFiles()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim Folder As Folder
Dim Files As Files
Dim path, s As String

'' Input Path : Please change as needed
path = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set Basefolder = fso.GetFolder(path)
Set SubFolders = Basefolder.SubFolders
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each Folder In SubFolders
    Set Files = Folder.Files
    For Each File In Files
       With Sheets("Sheet1")
       .Cells(i, 1).Value = Folder
       .Cells(i, 2).Value = File
       i = i + 1
    Next File
Next Folder
End Sub
```